# Can't connect to Internet. Networks not being detected. Fresh installation

Tags: release-freya, settings, luna, networking, ubuntu

I can't connect to the internet on my ASUS Desktop ROG G20AJ PC. I believe it has something to do with not having the correct drivers installed. I have built in wireless but cannot connect or detect any networks - even after manually adding a wireless network.

How can I manually download and install the driver(s)? And how do I know which ones to download/install?

Comment: You have tagged your question with freya, luna and ubuntu. Which of them do you use?

Answer (score 1):

**Identifying a Network device**

Running the `sudo lshw -c network` command in a terminal will display information regarding all network devices including the chipset and current driver in use.

The `lspci` or `lsusb` commands also provide useful information on all PCI/USB devices.

**Driver Installation**

Please update your question with the chipset and driver (if any) from the above commands and we can attempt to find a solution for this part.

Comment: This Asus model come with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 card onboard from factory. Try to install the correct driver with Aditional Drivers tab on Software Propierties.